# Testing InAppPurchase Ionic native plugin without paid developer account

Tags: cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I haven't yet purchased an Apple developer subscription but I want to test  the `InAppPurchase` plugin without one for the time being.

I know you can set up dummy accounts in Itunes Connect to test iAPs in sandbox mode, but the issue is I don't have any product data to import.

Specifically, in the doc's found here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/inapppurchase/ , it specifies that you need to first import your products as following:

```
InAppPurchase
 .getProducts(['com.yourapp.prod1', 'com.yourapp.prod2', ...])
 .then((products) => {
   console.log(products);
    //  [{ productId: 'com.yourapp.prod1', 'title': '...', description: '...', price: '...' }, ...]
 })
 .catch((err) => {
   console.log(err);
 });
```

Is there any way to create dummy productID's (e.g. `com.yourapp.prod1`) with only a free 7-day developer account? Alternatively, is there any publicly available productID's I can use for testing?